# Envío de notificaciones push

Tags: php, javascript, firebase, nativescript

Estoy realizando una app móvil con la tecnología de NativeScript y tengo un panel **backend PHP** para el envío de *notificaciones push*, tengo entendido que desde la app necesito enviar el **token** hacia una BD (en este caso quiero utilizar Firebase), y luego usar la api de firebase para llevarme los token al panel backend de PHP para poder enviar notificaciones push a través de un formulario a todos los dispositivos.
Tengo los archivos **google-services** incluidos en los directorios de Android e iOS.

Tengo el siguiente código:

**app.js**

```
var applicationModule = require("application");
applicationModule.start({ moduleName: "main-page" });

var pushPlugin = require("nativescript-push-notifications");

var pushSettings = {
        senderID: "XXXXXXXXXXXX", // Required: setting with the sender/project number
        notificationCallbackAndroid: function (stringifiedData, fcmNotification) {
            var notificationBody = fcmNotification && fcmNotification.getBody();
            _this.updateMessage("Message received!\n" + notificationBody + "\n" + stringifiedData);
        }
    };
pushPlugin.register(pushSettings, function (token) {
    alert(token);
}, function() { });
```

Dependencias del **package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "nativescript-push-notifications": "^1.1.4",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "tns-core-modules": "^3.4.1"
}
```

Desde mi **backend PHP** se envía perfectamente la notificación push al dispositivo, pero solo a uno ya que tengo que escribir manualmente el token de este en el código.

El objetivo es guardar en firebase los token generados y luego recorrerlos en el **backend PHP**, pero no sé como hacerlo porque no entiendo muy bien todo este concepto, ¿alguna ayudita por favor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No tengo como validar en este momento, pero lo mejor sería que cambies a [`nativescript-plugin-firebase`](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-plugin-firebase), pues tiene acceso a los diferentes productos de Firebase en el mismo plugin.

Podrías obtener el token y enviarlo a tu base de datos `Realtime Database` o a `Firestore`, entonces en tu backend obtener acceso a la lista de tokens.

Por ejemplo, en tu dispositivo:

```
const firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");
firebase.init({
    // Funcion Callback para cuando un mensaje es recibido
    onMessageReceivedCallback: (message) => {
      console.log(`Title: ${message.title}`);
      console.log(`Body: ${message.body}`);
    },
    // Funcion Callback para cuando se obtiene el token
    onPushTokenReceivedCallback: (token) => {
      console.log("Firebase push token: " + token);
      // Enviamos el token a la base de datos
      firebase.push('/tokensDeDispositivos', token)
        .then((result) => console.log("Token guardado"));
    }
});
```

En tu backend entonces puedes revisar en `Firebase Realtime Database` `/tokensDeDispositivos/`, que debería ser un array con los tokens de todos los dispositivos que se han registrado.

Eso puedes hacerlo con [`firebase-php`](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php). Pero ese es otro tema.

Más adelante puedes hacer algo para mantener la lista de tockens actualizada y depurada de los dispositivos que han perdido o cambiado su token. Pero ese es otro tema.

Comment: Editado porque había guardado la respuesta por accidente sin haber terminado de editarla.

Comment: Gracias por responder, me da error al lanzar **tns run android**, el error es _System.err: StackTrace:
System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266_. Tengo que importar typescript o algo ? He eliminado el plugin anterior y he incluido el que me has dicho.

Comment: Has seguido las instrucciones en la pagina del plugin?
Por lo poco que me muestras de tu stacktrace parece que hay errores al buscar el plugin.

Comment: Asegurate de correr `tns plugin add nativescript-plugin-firebase`

Comment: Sí, he corrido ese comando y tengo bien el require del plugin, puede ser por algo de typescript ? aunque también tengo typescript añadido  al package.json.

Comment: Aquí te paso el stacktrace completo del error: https://pastebin.com/shxctfYz

Comment: Creo que ya se que es... Es que yo te estoy dando el código en `TypeScript` y no en `JavaScript`. Ahorita mismo lo reparo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79786/discussion-between-nery-ortez-and-cifu).